# Java "pass-by-value" in a loop

Tags: java

I think this question is related to this question: [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value), but not really the same.

Suppose I have this loop code:

```
ArrayList<foo> list = new ArrayList<foo>();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, i);
    list.add(new foo(cal));
}
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    System.out.print(list.get(i).calToString());
}
```

foo.class:

```
public class foo {
    private Calendar mCal;
    public foo(Calendar cal) {
        mCal = cal;
    }
    public String calToString() {
        return String.valueOf(mCal.get(Calendar.HOUR));
    }
}
```

The resulting list has all its items `Calendar.HOUR` set to `9`.  It prints `9999999999`.  How can I make it so that each item will have 0-9 respectively?  Will instantiating variable `cal` inside the loop be a performance issue (if in case `foo` is a more complex class)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java pass by value Or pass by reference Or both?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249555/is-java-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference-or-both)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you are overwriting your object, you declared it outside the loop and you keep changing it's value.

You should create *new* instance inside the loop. No, you won't notice any performance issues.

Comment: Okay, I instantiated the Calendar variable inside the loop, but still kept the declaration outside, then it gave list items with 0-9.  But how is declaring the variable outside the loop different from declaring it inside the loop in terms of memory allocation?

Comment: In terms of memory allocation, in the first case, you only allocated memory for one object and overwrote it on each iteration. In the second case (my answer), you create a new object each time.

Comment: I meant the declaration.  I did what you said and instantiated inside the loop, but I kept the declaration outside.  What is the difference if I also moved the declaration inside the loop?

Comment: It's not different, the compiler will optimize that. The bytecode will be the same.

Comment: But please note that it's clearer to declare it outside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to initialize a new `Calendar` for each iteration of your loop.

Something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Otherwise, the same instance is referenced everytime.

Therefore, the `set` invocation modifies the same `Calendar`, which is why you are getting all `9`s.

More elegantly perhaps, you could initialize your `Foo` class with a constructor taking the actual hour `int`.

Then you would change `Foo` to have its own `Calendar` instance.

Answer (score 0):

class Main

{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    ArrayList<foo> list = new ArrayList<foo>();
    Calendar cal = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, i);
        list.add(new foo(cal));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        System.out.print(list.get(i).calToString());
    }
}
```

}

class foo {
    private Calendar    mCal;

```
public foo(Calendar cal) {
    mCal = cal;
}

public String calToString() {
    return String.valueOf(mCal.get(Calendar.HOUR));
}
```

}

you are overwriting your calender object